# Python pass second argument in method call based on if check

Tags: python

Is there any way to turn this psuedocode into real code?

```
get_quest_guide_char("isabelle", if game.location == "school_english_class": marker_sector="right_bottom"))
```

so marker_sector="right_bottom" only becomes the second argument based on the if check.

If the if check fails, the only argument passed is "isabelle"

Comment: What does `get_quest_guide_char` do with the `marker_sector` variable ? You'll have the option of just making it `None` or just not passing all together with an actual if statement, but the first one will depend if `get_quest_guide_char` will handle a `marker_sector=None` properly.

Answer (score 1):

Function/Methods are used to pass arguments based on their declaration and usage. Evaluation or doing any operation during declaration or usage is a bad approach and design.

What's the harm in using var-positional arguments i.e *args and *kwargs? The code should be simplified and not complicate. On top of that, think in terms of Unit testing your code function/code? Or may be you're not interested to unit test. Also I would recommend to go through [PEP-0362](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/)

You can do your evaluation in if condition and then pass it as argument. In your case you could simply do like below:

Your function declaration:

```
def get_quest_guide_char(name: str, **kwargs):
    if 'marker_sector' in kwargs:
        market_sector = kwargs.get('marker_sector')
```

If you need to pass multiple other parameters, you can iterate over the kwargs dict:

```
def get_quest_guide_char(name: str, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if key == 'marker_sector':
           market_sector = value
```

Usage:

```
 if value == "school_english_class":
        get_quest_guide_char(name="isabelle", marker_sector="right_bottom")
    else:
        get_quest_guide_char(name="isabelle")
```

NOTE: I used named parameter for value 'isabelle' to make things easier, you can choose to omit or use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
get_quest_guide_char("isabelle", marker_sector="right_bottom" if game.location == "school_english_class" else None))
```

This will pass to the function `"right_bottom"` only `if game.location == "school_english_class"` else it will pass None and then handle None in the function.
If you function defined as `get_quest_guide_char(isabelle_value, marker_sector)` then you can use just `"right_bottom" if game.location == "school_english_class" else None` without the `marker_sector=`.

Comment: This always needs a second argument. For me, I was trying to do if the if check fails, then there is not even second argument. So far best is this:

get_quest_guide_char("isabelle", **{"marker_sector": "right_bottom" for x in [1] * (game.location == "school_english_class")})

Comment: This line `**{"marker_sector": "right_bottom" for x in [1] * (game.location == "school_english_class")}` will pass the function `{"marker_sector": []} ` that same as `marker_sector = []` so you replace in my answer None with [] and it will be the same It's not the best practice to pass empty list to function.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to just build your extra parameter outside of the method call, it makes it easier to read specially if the method parameters starts increasing.

```py
params = {}
if game.location == "school_english_class":
    params['mark_sector'] = "right_bottom"

get_quest_guide_char("isabelle", **params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers before mine, this technically still passes at least two arguments. This is because function overloading isn't really a thing in Python, (having multiple functions with the same name). If you want a variable number of parameters, you can use `*args` and/or `**kwargs` when calling the function, but your function would still technically have to be defined with multiple arguments:

```
def get_quest_guide_char(character, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...

# or in your case
def get_quest_guide_char(character, *args):
    # ...
```

Or more explicitly:

```
def get_quest_guide_char(character, marker_sector=None):
    # ...
```

This will let you do both:

```
get_quest_guide_char("isabelle", marker_sector)

# and
get_quest_guide_char("isabelle")
```

Given that `marker_sector` depends on `game.location`, you could alternatively create another function that gives you the `marker_sector`, and simply pass that into your function regardless:

```
def get_marker_sector(location):
    if (location == "school_english_class"):
        marker_sector = "right_bottom"
    else:
        # ...

    return marker_sector

marker_sector = get_marker_sector(game.location)
get_quest_guide_char("isabelle", marker_sector):
```

Alternatively, you could just pass in `game.location` to your `get_quest_guide_char` function:

```
def get_quest_guide_char(character, location):
    if (location == "school_english_class"):
        # ...
    else:
        # ...

get_quest_guide_char("isabelle", game.location)
```

Either way, I hope you're not intending on using `marker_sector` as a global variable inside any of your functions. Mutable global variables are asking for trouble.